# JQuery AJAX on Error alert

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a CS:GO gamble site where user have to save his Steam Trade URL, i have made an JQuery AJAX post to save the data on database:

```
$(document).on('click', '#saveURL', function(e) {
    var data = $("#tradeURL").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        data: data,
        type: "post",
        url: "functions/tradeURL.php",
        success: function(data) {
            noty({
                text: '<b>Success!</b> <br>Your Trade URL is now saved.',
                layout: 'topRight',
                theme: 'metroui',
                type: 'success',
                maxVisible: 10,
                timeout: 5000,
                closeWith: ['click', 'timeout'],
                animation: {
                    open: {
                        height: 'toggle'
                    },
                    close: {
                        height: 'toggle'
                    },
                    easing: 'swing',
                    speed: 500 // opening & closing animation speed
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

If the data was submitted correctly it gives that alert, but my **tradeURL.php** contains this code:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST)) {
    $tradeURL = $_POST["tradeURL"];
    $tradeURL = htmlspecialchars(str_replace('', '', $tradeURL));
    $turl = explode("=", explode("&", "'.$tradeURL.'") [0]); // user trade url
    if ($turl[1] == $steamid - intval(0x0110000100000000)) {
        $update = "UPDATE users SET tlink='$tradeURL' WHERE steamid=$steamid";
        if ($db->query($update) === TRUE) {

            // THIS GIVES THE ALERT ON THE JQUERY SCRIPT

        }
        else {
            echo "Error updating record: " . $db->error;
        }
    }
    else {

        // HOW TO OUTPUT THIS ON THE AJAX POST ?

    }
}
```

So how i should make an alert to that part where it says **// HOW TO OUTPUT THIS ON THE AJAX POST ?** and it would save it to database.

Comment: I'm not expert or anything in Php, but cant you do this if you just want a simple alert in your php script `echo "<script>alert('HOW TO OUTPUT THIS ON THE AJAX POST ?')</script>` im sure there is better ways.

Comment: That won't work since the .php is in different direction and it would still output that noty alert that says success.

Comment: Okay sorry, was just a guess, But now im confused, do you want the alert in your php code or in the ajax ?

Comment: In the ajax if that would be possible someway.

Comment: Cant you then do `success: function(data) {}, error: function(data) { alert("THIS IS AN ERROR")}` ? just add the error part after your success

Answer (score 0):

You can echo some value there:

```
// HOW TO OUTPUT THIS ON THE AJAX POST ?
echo "Invalid value."; // or your choice of text...
```

Now in the success callback use this:

```
success: function(data) {
    if(data === 'Invalid value.'){ // <--add this one
       alert(data);
       return;
    }
    noty({
        ...
    });
}
```

Comment: That did not worked, it did not output that **alert(data):** but it still output that noty alert and did not saved the data to database

Answer (score 0):

Hi you dont output alerts for JS within PHP. Your php should return something like:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
if($correct){
    echo json_encode(array("status" => true));
}else{
    echo json_encode(array("status" => false));
}
die; // note: this should not be used, instead you shoud make sure there is no other output on page.
```

And then within your javascript you interpret your responce:

```
if(data.status == true){
    //display message that input accepted
} else {
    //display message that input is not valid
}
```

Comment: make sure to `exit;` at the end.

Comment: That is what the die; and and comment next to it is for.